# in a tuple, why is x[0] not equal to x[:1]? for tuple x = (1, 2, (3, 'John', 4), 'Hi')

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Given the tuple 
`x = (1, 2, (3, 'John', 4), 'Hi')`
why `x[0] = 1` returns an int, but `x[0:1] = (1,)` returns a tupple? 
I can see x[0:1]  seems to not be equal to x[0], but why?
(this is from an exercise from MIT 6.00.1 course, thanks in advance)

Comment: When you use [0] python "knows" you are expecting 1 element to be returned.
When you use [0:1] even if it only returns 1 element the notation is expected to return multiple elements.

Basically, just because it looks similar doesn't mean it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both `x[0:1]` and `x[:1]` will return a tuple.
It returns `(1,)` because you told Python to give you the elements from the range 0 to 1 and not just a single element.